# How does Google Chrome's dev tools emulate device mode? How to replicate it with extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, responsive-design, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools, emulation

I need to open Instagram in mobile mode as it shows Messages tab only in mobile view. I want to know what Chrome does so I can replicate it in my Chrome extension.

I've already noticed Google Chrome updates the User Agent. I have however tried this and replaced the headers with "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Mobile Safari/537.36" but this doesn't seem enough for Instagram to show mobile view. I suspect Google Chrome does something extra or Instagram has some safety measure?

```
let mobileAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Mobile Safari/537.36";

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
        details.requestHeaders[i].value = mobileAgent;
        j=i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
  },
  {urls: ["*://*.instagram.com/*"]},
["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

With above code, I checked the headers and sure enough they are using mobile agent but Instagram still doesn't display messages tab.

Comment: As we can see in the source code devtools uses RDP method [setDeviceMetricsOverride](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setDeviceMetricsOverride) which you can also use in an extension with the help of chrome.debugger API, look for examples and experiment yourself.